# can somebody help python beginner?

Tags: python

2) user must enter 4 decimal numbers (it could be any number bigger than 0)
 with these number, i have to combine these numbers to make biggest number 
for example) enter 23,8,313,72-----> answer is 87231323

but you have to use command "list"

```
for i in range(0,4,1):
    for j in range(0,4,1):
        for u in range(0,4,1):
            for k in range(0,4,1):
                if (i!=j) and (i!=u) and (i!=k) and (j!=u) and (j!=k) and (u!=k):
                    text = a[i] + a[j] + a[u] + a[k]
                else:
```

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577) and [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You could sort it as if it was a list of strings, and then join them together:

```
l = [23, 8, 313, 72]
print(''.join(sorted([str(item) for item in l], reverse=True)))
```

Returns: `87231323`